# What do I set for the standard deviation of a measurement, if the value is not normally distributed?

Tags: experimental-physics, data-analysis

I took multiple $B$ measurements for a constant $A$ value, which I simultaneously measured.

$A$ (in my case the resistance of a temperature sensor) was controlled by a PID controlled and slowly oscillated in the range 2596 to 2560.

It is tempting to just say that $A=2598\pm2$ but is this really correct? Because the value stayed at the turning points 2596 and 2560 the longest, not at 2598, so the "time spent" is not normally distributed over the range 2956-2600. This feels like cheating.

Or would it be best to just say $A=2560$ and don't give a statistical error at all, but only a possible systematic error due to a potential offset?

I'm really bad with these fundamental experimental questions.

Comment: More detail would be helpful.  Was the temperature sensor control loop (aka PID controller) closed at the time that you took your measurements?  How do you know that the temperature was steady when you were measuring it?  What does the control loop look like?

Comment: Yes the control loop was closed all the time.

Comment: @DavidWhite The control loop is inside of the power supply, I can't see it directly. I turned of the D component completely and tuned P and I until I was happy with the convergence of the controller. I waited 3 minutes between each measurement, after some time the large overshooting/undershooting of the target value  stoped and faded out to small and steady oscillations, then I wrote down the temperature and oscillation range and started to do the actual B measurement.

Comment: TheoreticalMinimum, I worked for a large refiner in process control for 15 years.  My comments: keep "D" out of the tuning; for large overshoot, you may have too much gain (aka "P").  Start with "P" only, make setpoint changes, and don't worry about "offset" yet ... just play around with "P" until you get a reasonable approach to the setpoint.  Lastly, play around with "I" (integral) to eliminate offsets from setpoint.  Note - as long as the control loop is closed, control action is being taken, and it is impossible to hold the temperature exactly at the setpoint.  (See next comment)

Comment: Due to that fact, taking measurements and asking for a standard deviation of the measurement probably doesn't make sense, because the temperature is being manipulated by the controller, so it definitely isn't constant, which is the hidden assumption when you are trying to collect enough data to calculate a standard deviation on a measurement.

Comment: @David White thank you! I learned it the hard way, that keeping D out of tuning helps haha! I just converted the resistance measurement to temperature and it turns out it was oscillating by just 0.05 Degree Kelvin! This is completely irrelevant to my application, as I'm doing 1 K steps. So what would you do in this case, just put e.g. $(24.2\pm0.1)K$? This is a conservative estimate then and I don't really care about the small loss in precision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116072/discussion-between-david-white-and-theoreticalminimum).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be normally distributed. e.g. Binomial distribution also has a mean and variance (${\sigma^2}$). If you are interested in your distribution form you can plot a histogram and see it yourself. Note: not all distributions have variances (e.g. Cauchy distribution).

Comment: Yes but the variance is not necessarily the value range right? And I only recorded the value range of the resistance ($A$).

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum By definition SDV is only related to your data set, but to capture the accurate variance of your probability distribution you might want to increase your sample size depending on how many data points you've taken. For example, to capture a normal distribution's variance on Mathematica simulation, I got a good result for about 3000 points.

Answer (score 0):

For a set of data, even if you do not know the underlying type of probability distribution, you can calculate the standard deviation of the data. This is called the standard deviation of the sample.

The standard deviation also applies for any probability distribution function, discrete or continuous: normal, binomial, exponential, beta etc. (excluding some odd ones).  This is the standard deviation of the population as opposed to the standard deviation of a sample.  The relationship for calculating the standard deviation from a sample is slightly different from the relationship for calculating the standard deviation for the population.

See any basic statistics textbook for the equation for the standard deviation for a sample that you can apply to your data (and, the equation for calculating the standard deviation for a population, and the relationships for the standard deviations for the different types of probability distributions).

Comment: I mean this would work if I would know how long the temperature/resistance was at which value. Then I could determine the mean value and the StdDev. But I don't know this, I only know it's value range and it's central value. So I need to estimate it more or less I guess.

Comment: If you knew the time for each value you could weight the values by the times, but I guess you do not know that?  Another approach is to not use classical objective probability/statistical inference but instead use a Bayesian approach based on your subjective state of knowledge updated by your data.  Another approach when your state of knowledge is poor is to use the belief/plausibility measure of uncertainty.  You can find discussions of Bayesian and belief/plausibility in the literature; it takes time to understand these.  Hope this helps.